# Resources for data on security incidents

Tags: attacks, research, threats

What resources exist to research data on actual security incidents?

I would prefer an online resource but offline resources are acceptable. The cost of access should be less than $100 (US) for access to a statistically significant number of incidents. I would prefer databases that include more than just media reported security incidents.

I know of one online database [RISI](http://www.securityincidents.org/) but a membership there is $995 (US) for 3 month access to their database. Are there similar databases at a lower cost?

Comment: Is it the raw data you are after? Not things like Verizon's DBIR?

Comment: @Rory at the moment anything is better then nothing. Raw data is better but group data is fine.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions of the type "where can I find X?" are off-topic because they do not age well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My group has often used the [OSF DataLoss DB](http://datalossdb.org/) for some comparative statistical analysis. By and large the data is gathered through public sources, either reported on the web or by issuing Freedom of Information requests to the various agencies that process breach notifications.

The real benefit is that this information is free, and made available as a downloadable database. As such post processing can go very nice and smooth.

Answer (score 7):

Ones I tend to draw on:

[Verizon Data Breach Report](http://www.verizonbusiness.com/resources/reports/rp_2010-data-breach-report_en_xg.pdf) - this is generally considered THE source on data breaches

[Krebs Java Security Report](http://krebsonsecurity.com/2010/10/java-a-gift-to-exploit-pack-makers/) - Krebs is very well respected - various studies, of which this is a grand example

[WHID Security Report](https://files.pbworks.com/download/loBVUfSYDp/webappsec/29750234/WHIDWhitePaper_WASC.pdf) - also very useful

These are all freely available online, and updated versions available annually (or more often in the case of Krebs)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe helpful? [Identity Theft Resource Center](http://www.idtheftcenter.org/artman2/publish/lib_survey/ITRC_2008_Breach_List.shtml) (http://www.idtheftcenter.org/artman2/publish/lib_survey/ITRC_2008_Breach_List.shtml)

2011 breach list:  http://www.idtheftcenter.org/ITRC%20Breach%20Report%202011.pdf

Answer (score 1):

It's more at the meta level of what happens the most, and doesn't cover specific incidents in detail, but every year the US gov't releases the Top 25 Dangerous Software Errors which references the Common Weakness Enumeration which is a break down of every know category of vulnerability.

2011's top 25 can be [found here](http://cwe.mitre.org/top25/).

Comment: While that list is great for some purposes, it is a list of vulnerabilities rather than a list of breaches.  If you want to find out what bad guys are actually exploiting or what failures are occurring in the field, a list of common vulnerabilities doesn't help much.

Answer (score -1):

This list might be helpful, this a list of [UK cyber attacks and data breaches](https://nicolsonbray.com/insights/cyber-attacks/uk-cyber-attacks-data-breaches-list-october-2022), which we started gathering earlier this year.  It is just media reported incidents however, as non media reported ones tend to be hard to find out about.

Comment: This is just a list of links to media reports, and not suitable for research, as asked for by the OP. And it's UK-specific. I'm not sure how this is any different from a Google search.