# Incident database?

Tags: incident-response

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resources for data on security incidents](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5339/resources-for-data-on-security-incidents)

Do you know any websites where they put Information about Security Incidents that happened to organizations/people (e.g. breakins, data leaks, etc.) in a categorized/searchable way?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you familiar with the [CERT](http://www.us-cert.gov/nvd.html) database?

> US-CERT and NVD
>          What is the NVD?
>
> The National Vulnerability Database (NVD) is a product of the National
>   Institute of Standards and Technology (NIST) Computer Security
>   Division and is sponsored by the Department of Homeland Security's
>   (DHS) National Cyber Security Division. US-CERT resources are found in
>   the NVD, particularly vulnerability notes and technical alerts. NVD is
>   a comprehensive cyber security vulnerability database that integrates
>   all publicly available U.S. Government vulnerability resources and
>   provides references to industry resources. It is based on and
>   synchronized with the Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures (CVE®)
>   vulnerability naming standard.
>
> NVD was created to provide technical capabilities and support for a
>   variety of vulnerability standards. NVD's mission involves warning the
>   public about vulnerabilities in computer systems. NVD helps DHS
>   fulfill that mission by offering vulnerability information on all
>   publicly known computer vulnerabilities. As far as technical
>   capabilities, NVD provides this information using a search engine
>   while integrating all publicly available U.S. government vulnerability
>   resources. All of this information is given away for free with no
>   licensing restrictions through XML and RSS feeds.
>
> Statistics on the nature of vulnerabilities are provided through the
>   NVD statistics engine. This service allows users to assess changes in
>   vulnerability discovery rates within specific products or within
>   specific types of vulnerabilities. The NVD statistics engine allows
>   one to generate statistics on vulnerability trends over time. One can
>   track particular products or vendors. Alternately, one can track sets
>   of vulnerabilities with particular attributes (such as remotely
>   exploitable buffer overflows). The statistics engine can also look at
>   the past history of a product as an indicator to see whether or not it
>   is likely to be vulnerable in the future.
>
> NVD is
>
> ```
> A comprehensive cyber security vulnerability database that integrates all publicly available U.S. Government vulnerability
> ```
>
> resources and provides references to industry resources
>       A vulnerability database that integrates Open Vulnerability Assessment Language (OVAL) queries
>       Based on and synchronized with the CVE® vulnerability naming standard
>       Free to the public on the NVD website

Comment: I'm familiar with it, but I want something a little bit less technical, i.e. "This happened because of a lack of privilege separation controls"